# c++: cin.getline is ignored in a separate case

Tags: c++, getline

For some reasons the `string cin.getline (temp.Autor, 20)` is ignored. Please, have a look at [the output](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!122&authkey=!ABlqPFsRAyHMGPk)
Could you help me understand why?

```
struct BOOK {
    char Autor[20]; 
    char Title[50]; 
    short Year; 
    int PageCount;
    double Cost;
};                  

void new_book()
{
    BOOK temp;
    system("cls");
    cout <<"ENTERING NEW BOOK: " << endl <<endl;
    cout <<"Input the author: ";
    cin.getline (temp.Autor, 20);
    cout  <<"Input the title: ";
    cin.getline (temp.Title, 50);
    cout  <<"Input the year of publishing: ";
    cin >>  temp.Year;
    cout  <<"Input the number of pages: ";
    cin >>  temp.PageCount;
    cout  <<"Input the cost: ";
    cin >>  temp.Cost;
    cout << endl;   
    print_book(temp);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: If you're not being forced to use character arrays, I suggest switching over to `std::string` and using `std::getline`.

Comment: No, I'm not about that. I'm perfectly happy with chars. What warries me is why one line is ignored whereas similar line works perfectly.

Comment: Have you another input before it?(e.g number of books) It's possible that you have unread "\n" at the end of one of the prev input strings. After that you read the rest of this line i.e nothing

Comment: @Kifsif: you may be happy (till you shoot yourself in the foot), but your users will not. After all, who said that "Christos Dimitriou Papakyriakopoulos" is an invalid author?

Comment: @Kifsif, First of all, character arrays will only cause you pain and torture. Even now, you can only input up to a certain length because of the size of the arrays. You'll thank yourself later after you practice using `std::string` and get accustomed to it. It's just plain quick and easy to use, safe, and hassle-free. Anyway, I strongly suspect a `cin >> something` before this function call.

Comment: Well, this is a learning task. It is not me who invented such a structure. And I can't change it. As for the line, I tried everything - I have already deleted almost the whole block. I changed the lines. Well, the problem is still here.

Comment: @Kifsif: *"It is not me who invented such a structure. And I can't change it."*. Whoever has come up with this struct, is a bad bad guy. He is an enemy of C++, especially Modern C++.

Comment: Well, I agree that it is not a very good idea. But this is not a problem, really. The problem is the ignored cin.

Comment: your code looks ok, the problem must be in some other routine where you leave stuff in the cin. you could try to adding cin.ignore() before reading "Autor"

Comment: possible duplicate of [getline not asking for input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642865/getline-not-asking-for-input)

Answer (score 6):

> "It is not me who invented such a structure. And I can't change it.".

Whoever has come up with this struct, is a bad bad guy. He is an enemy of C++, especially Modern C++.  Even if he has a PhD in Computer Science, he is a bad bad guy, and doesn't know where to start studying C++. He might be good in other concepts of CS, but he is not good at all in C++. Because of such instructors, C++ has got the bad name, when C++ is **not** *that* bad.

Now coming back to the struct. Show him this struct:

```
struct Book 
{
    std::string Author; 
    std::string Title; 
    short Year; 
    int PageCount;
    double Cost;
};
```

And ask him what is wrong with this struct, especially with the `std::string` members? Ask him for *reason(s)* as to why you shouldn't *prefer* this instead of *char-array*. Why he thinks *raw-char-array* is better than `std::string`?

Whatever reason(s) he come up with, just tell him : FOR GOD SAKE, LEARN REAL C++.

There is NOTHING wrong in learning *raw-char-array*,  *pointers*, or *memory-management*. The point is that these concepts should be taught at the later stage of your course, not in the beginning. I repeat NOT IN THE BEGINNING.  Your assignment does show that *it is the beginning* of the course.  So in the beginning, the students should be taught `std::string`, `std::vector` and other containers, and algorithms from the standard library.

Once the students learn these, they can go ahead with how they're implemented, where comes the details such as raw-array, pointers, memory-management, and hell lots of things.  These are *advanced* topics which come with problems as well as *idiomatic* solutions, most popular being RAII which solves the memory-management elegantly. That is to say, a student should NEVER be taught about `new` and `delete` *alone*, he should be taught [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) *along* with it.

Now coming back to HOW to *read* data into the members of the previously defined struct:

```
Book book;

//assuming each value is on its own line!
if ( !std::getline(std::cin, book.Author) ) 
{
     std::cerr << "Error while reading Author \n";
}
//read data into other members
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The `cin` function stops reading when it finds a space. Use `getline` to read the author and book names.

Read this question for more information:

[Why does the program loop infinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611279/why-does-the-program-loop-infinitely/9611330#9611330)